# Where i should place try catch block? (Simple division method)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, methods

It's my code:

```
 using System;

 using System.Data;

 using System.Transactions;

 namespace BasicCourse.Exceptions 
 {

    class Program
    {
   
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       
       Division();

       Console.ReadKey();
       }

      static void Division()
      {
        Console.Write("Enter a first number: ");
        int firstEnteredNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter a second number: ");
        int secondEnteredNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        float quotient = (float) firstEnteredNumber / secondEnteredNumber;

        Console.WriteLine("Result of division: " + quotient + "\n");
      }
}
```

}

I'm learning the exceptions in C#.I want to attend the divide by zero exception but i don't know where should i place a try catch block.In Main method:

```
try 
{ 
    Division() 
} 
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
 etc...?
```

Or inside the `Division` method?

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use a try/catch and instead I'd check if `secondEnteredNumber` was zero before doing the division.

Comment: inside the main, the reason for that is it should be the callers responsibility to handle exceptions, in this case the caller is `Main`

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user enters a 0 as the second number?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 1):

Update --- Sorry!
I read others' answers and found that float don't throw any exceptions!I'm so sorry for I forgot it.

> [DivideByZeroException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception)
> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an **integral** or **decimal** value by zero.

The console shows:

> Result of division: ∞

In fact, we don't want this type of result, so I edited the answer.

---

So we know the result is: no exception throwed.
If you want method Division() to remind users that they are trying to divide by 0, you can check the value.

```cs
      static void Division()
      {
        Console.Write("Enter a first number: ");
        int firstEnteredNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter a second number: ");
        int secondEnteredNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Added
        if (secondEnteredNumber == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cannot divide by 0");
        }
        else
        {
            float quotient = (float) firstEnteredNumber / secondEnteredNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("Result of division: " + quotient + "\n");
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Division();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Dividing by zero doesn't result in an exception. You would have to put in some logic to handle it.

```
            if (float.IsNaN(quotient))
        {
            //dostuff
        }
```